# Adding encryption key to already created S3 Bucket object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, amazon-kms

I have a bucket created in a different region without encryption. I want to add a KMS encryption to the bucket object

```
@staticmethod
def change_bucket_encryption(
        stack: Stack,
        bucket_arn: str,
        bucket_id: str,
        kms_key: aws_kms.Key) -> s3.Bucket:
    """Change bucket encryption."""
    bucket = s3.Bucket.from_bucket_arn(
        scope=stack,
        id=bucket_id,
        bucket_arn=bucket_arn
    )
    bucket.encryption_key = kms_key
    return bucket
```

This is throwing the error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'encryption_key'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the AWS CDK documentation correct key is `encryptionKey` and not *encryption_key*

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-s3-readme.html

Or if you're not using this way then share more details on the framework, language, sdk, etc.

Comment: Wow... That helped. I was using python and maybe I didn't understand it right, but the documentation was using encryption_key and got me confused https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/README.html

Comment: This is not correct at all. The actual attribute name in Python is `encryption_key`. The issue is that it is not possible to modify imported resources, so this attribute cannot be set, only read.